# Page numbering resets after table of contents (roman/arabic)

Tags: page-numbering

For some reason my page numbering restarts after table of context and changes from roman to arabic numbers. I don't really know how to make MWE for this because I use include to put text into the document. Here is how that part of the code looks like:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
     citecolor=black,
     filecolor=black,
     linkcolor=black,
     urlcolor=black
}
\pagenumbering{roman}%
\begin{spacing}{1.4}%
\tableofcontents
\end{spacing}
\clearpage
\begin{spacing}{1}
\input{Text/Introduction}
\end{spacing}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\include{Text/MainText}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\blindtext
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

With this I get roman numbering for table of contents, as it should, but after that the Introduction chapter starts with arabic numbering instead to continue roman numbering.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: the `\pagenumbering` command takes effect immediately, on the current page-in-progress.  to delay it until the next page, insert a `\clearpage` before you issue `\pagenumbering`.

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand what you mean. I don't want to delay anything. I want my introduction to continue the roman page numbering of the table of contents.

Comment: Ignore my last comment! Inserting /clearpage before \pagenumbering{arabic} solved the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

the `\pagenumbering` command takes effect immediately, on the current page-in-progress.
i suspect that your introduction is not more than one page long, so that would still be
"live" when you reset `\pagenumbering{arabic}`.

to delay the effect of this command, insert `\clearpage` before you issue `\pagenumbering`.