# new section ignores pagenumbering roman

Tags: report, roman-numerals, unnumbered-sections

In `report` class, I want to create an unnumbered Introduction chapter with few subsection. The pages up to the Introduction (including table of contents) should have roman number. After Introduction, the pages should be arabic and restart from 1. Unfortunately, my Introduction section remains in arabic even if I do not change the `\pagenumbering` back to arabic, and furthermore it starts counting from 1 again even if I set a `\setcounter{page}{1}` afterwards. How to fix this?

Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass[notitlepage]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref,todonotes,longtable}
\usepackage{graphics,epsfig,lscape,setspace,url,setspace,morefloats,comment,booktabs,color}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[labelfont=sc, singlelinecheck=false, font={small}]{caption}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[flushmargin,hang,marginal,multiple, stable]{footmisc}
\usepackage{titling}

\hypersetup{pdfborder = {0 0 0}}

\renewcommand{\abstractname}{\bf ABSTRACT}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{chapquote}[2][2em]
  {\setlength{\@tempdima}{#1}%
   \def\chapquote@author{#2}%
   \parshape 1 \@tempdima \dimexpr\textwidth-2\@tempdima\relax%
   \itshape}
  {\par\normalfont\hfill \chapquote@author\hspace*{\@tempdima}\par\bigskip}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{plain}

\renewcommand{\abstractname}{\bf ABSTRACT}

\makeatletter
\def\blfootnote{\gdef\@thefnmark{}\@footnotetext}
\makeatother

\title{main title\\
{\Large somewhere}}
\author{Author 1}
\date{}

\begin{document}

% Two empty pages
\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage
\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage


\setcounter{page}{1}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\maketitle

\pagenumbering{roman}
%\renewcommand{\thepage}{\roman{page}}
\chapter*{Acknowledgment}

\begin{center}
    something here
\end{center}

% Empty page after acknowledgement
\newpage\null
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage

\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Introduction and Summary}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction and Summary}
\section*{Chapter 1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Chapter 1}
\section*{Chapter 2}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Chapter 2}
\section*{Chapter 3}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Chapter 3}

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\setcounter{page}{1}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}} 

\chapter{My chapter 1}
\title{\LARGE{\bf My chap 1 \vspace{0.5cm}} }
\author{\small \sc{Author1\thanks{Affiliation 1}}} %to mute
\date{}
\maketitle\emptythanks
\begin{abstract}{\noindent An abstract
\blfootnote{We thank X} %to mute
}
\end{abstract}
\thispagestyle{empty} \newpage
\section{Sec1}   
\section{Sec2}   

\chapter{My chapter 2}
\title{\LARGE{\bf My chap 2 \vspace{0.5cm}} }
\author{\small \sc{Author2\thanks{Affiliation 2}}} %to mute
\date{}
\maketitle\emptythanks
\begin{abstract}{\noindent An abstract
\blfootnote{We thank X} %to mute
}
\end{abstract}
\thispagestyle{empty} \newpage
\section{Sec1}   
\section{Sec2}   

\chapter{My chapter 3}
\title{\LARGE{\bf My chap 3 \vspace{0.5cm}} }
\author{\small \sc{Author3\thanks{Affiliation 3}}} %to mute
\date{}
\maketitle\emptythanks
\begin{abstract}{\noindent An abstract
\blfootnote{We thank X} %to mute
}
\end{abstract}
\thispagestyle{empty} \newpage
\section{Sec1}   
\section{Sec2}   


\end{document}
```

The table of contents is in roman number, but Introduction is arabaic, and it starts at 1 instead of continuing with roman numbers. Chapter 1 should start with arabic page 1[image]

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution which is very easy. Base on this [Page numbering resets after table of contents (roman/arabic)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194976/page-numbering-resets-after-table-of-contents-roman-arabic), "the \pagenumbering command takes effect immediately, on the current page-in-progress... to delay the effect of this command, insert \clearpage before you issue \pagenumbering."

Hence, I simply add `\clearpage` after the the tocs added to the table of contents, obtaining the desired result.